Data Fetching with suspense and route params in Vue3 Composition Api
this is children component
<script setup>
import { computed, ref, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import dataSource from '../../data.json'
import destinationApi from '@/services/destinationApi'
console.log(dataSource)

const route = useRoute()
watchEffect(() => {
  console.log(route.params)
})

const destination = ref(null)
const slug = computed(() => route.params.slug)
watch(
  () => slug.value,
  async () => {
    try {
      const res = await destinationApi.getDestination(slug.value)
      destination.value = res.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  },
  { immediate: true },
)
</script>

<template>
  <section class="destination" v-if="destination">
    <h1>{{ destination.name }}</h1>
    <div class="destination-details">
      <img :src="/images/${destination.image}" :alt="destination.name" />
      <p>{{ destination.description }}</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

and this is parent Components
<script setup>
import DestinationComp from '@/components/DestinationComp.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <Suspense>
    <DestinationComp />
    <template #fallback>
      <h1>..loading</h1>
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>

when im using suspense fallback does not showing i know fetching should be top level code but then page does not changing when route.param is changing, is there some solution could you help me ?
